# How to do error message when I write double number in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I have the following question:

> Develop a program of GUI calculator which would report exception. Note that Number 1 or Number 2 were non-numeric String, the program would report exception to the user. The program must contain an exception handler to catch ArithmeticException (e.g. divied by 0) and NumberFormatException (e.g., input is not an integer), display the errors in a message dialog box as shown below.

[image]

I don't know how to do error message when I write double numbers.

This is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.util.InputMismatchException;

   import javax.swing.*;

   public class Q1 extends JApplet {

   private JTextField Num1, Num2, Result;

   private JButton jbtDiv = new JButton("Divide");

 public Q1() {

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
p1.add(new JLabel("Number 1"));
p1.add(Num1 = new JTextField(3));
p1.add(new JLabel("Number 2"));
p1.add(Num2 = new JTextField(3));
p1.add(new JLabel("Result"));
p1.add(Result = new JTextField(4));
Result.setEditable(false);
Result.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(jbtDiv, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

jbtDiv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      String  output2= "Number format error";
      int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText().trim());


      int num2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText().trim());

      int result = num1 / num2;





      Result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
      //continueInput = false;


  } 
  });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");

  Q1 applet = new Q1();

  frame.getContentPane().add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  frame.setSize(400, 100);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
  }
```

Comment: Catch the exception from `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: "*i have this question*" You mean assignment? That's definitely not a question

Comment: Start by following the instructions: _"The program must contain an exception handler to catch ArithmeticException ... and NumberFormatException"_ - that's the key to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an assignment. You can do some *try-catch* things to handle exceptions.
For example,

```
new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String  output2= "Number format error";
        try{
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText().trim());


            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText().trim());

            int result = num1 / num2;

            Result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            //continueInput = false;

        } catch (){// parse exception
            // popup dialog for format error
        } catch (){// divide by 0
            // popup dialog for ArithmeticException
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is hardly an answer, and if it is then it's hardly correct.

Comment: @user1803551 It's following your comment. I want to know why it is not an answer.

Comment: Looking at it again, I didn't see the `try` with the way it's shoved in. You should indent the code properly and I'll remove the -1.

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying to keep the same format as OP posted. I edited.